# Remove Firefox Custom Search

Tags: firefox, search, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint 10. I would like to how to remove Google custom search results page in Firefox. I would like to have standard Google search results page instead of custom search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps in this article: [How To Remove Linux Mint Custom Google Search in Firefox.](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=39623)

Comment: Try this one: [How To Remove Linux Mint Custom Google Search in Firefox](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=39623).

Comment: Shouldn't your answer contain the important steps? External sources might vanish or move to other locations over time.

Answer (score 3):

You can customise the Firefox toolbar.

- Right click on the toolbar and choose Customize.
- Another window should come out, click and drag the Google search bar from the toolbar into the newly opened window.

This will remove the Google search bar from Firefox.